# My application does not backout messages - IBM MQ

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq, message-queue

I'm  writing a springboot app which use a JmsListener to read messages from a queue, and i want to backout them if an exception during the queue detachement, occurs. So whenever a new message is added to my inputQueue, the listener parse the message and populate an entity. Trough MQExplorer i have set up my 2 queues, the BO one has a treshold of '1' so after one ping-pong of the message, it is delivered in the BO queue. Of course, the main queue has the proper BO queue set up, trough the 'memory' panel. I think the code is correctly written but something does not works properly. Trough debug, i can see that exceptions are properly raised and caught but the @Transactional does not put the message in the backout queue even if the rollback occurs. I also tried to use another queue but the result is the same. Here some of my classes:

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    @RestController
    @Configuration
    @EnableJms
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @EnableJpaRepositories
    @EntityScan
    public class myApplication{

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(myApplication.class, args);
  }

    }
```

---

```
    @Component
    public class MyListenerXML{
@JmsListener(destination = "inputQUeue")
public void receiveMessage(Message message) throws Exception, Throwable {
try {
            // My instructions
            //This must be transactional  
             doTransaction();
            //This does not need to be transactional 
            foo(); 
} catch (JmsException e) {
        throw e;        
} catch (ReadMessageException e) {
        throw e.getCause();
} catch (JAXBException e) {
        logger.error("Parsing Error!");
        throw e;
} catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error during commit", e.getMessage());
        throw e;
}
}


}




@Transactional(rollbackOn={JAXBException.class,ReadMessageException.class, Exception.class})
public MyEntityObject doTransaction(Message message) throws JAXBException,Exception {
    MyEntityObject myEntityObject = null;
try {
        //My instructions...
        }
} catch (JAXBException e) {
        throw e;
} catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error in the transaction phase!: {}", e.getMessage());
        throw new ReadMessageException(e);
}
    return myEntityObject ;

}
 }


 public String foo (){...}
```

So as you see i use the @Transactional on the doTransaction() since it has to be atomic, and if i try to break an input XML message, the exceptions are correctly threw. Anyway, the transactions rollbacks but the message doesn't ends up in the backout queue.

What i'm missing?

EDIT: For what concern authorizations, i do not have any usr and pwd but they will be provided later on so i'm setting up the properties as well. This is the class used to the defintion of my main queue.

```
        @Bean
public MQQueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    MQQueueConnectionFactory factory = null;
    try {
        factory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
        factory.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, hostname);
        factory.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_NAME_LIST, hostname);
        factory.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT, port);
        factory.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, channel);
        factory.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
        factory.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, queueManager);
        factory.setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP, userAuthMQCSP);
        factory.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.USERID, user);
        factory.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.PASSWORD, password);
        factory.createConnection(user, password);
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        logger.error("Error in MQ defintion" + e.getMessage());
    }
    return factory;
}

  @Bean
public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() {
    return new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory());
}

   @Bean
  public JmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
      DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory =
              new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
      factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
      return factory;
  }
```

Comment: I may be mis-reading this, but your description suggests that the Backout Threshold is set on the Backout queue and not on the main application queue? In order for the JMS classes to use the Backout Threshold, the number must be set on the main application queue.

Comment: No, the backout is set on the main application queue. @MoragHughson

Comment: Can you update the question with the main queue definition and the OAM permission you have granted the user for the BO queue and the queue manager?

Comment: @JoshMc question updated.

Comment: The questions I have a related to the queue manager config,  can you provide that?

Comment: i used this as tutorial (https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/learn-mq/mq-tutorials/develop-mq-jms/) and i do not instantiate any Qmanager since in the beginning it was working fine

Comment: That is all client side.   I am asking you for the queue manager configurations, "the main queue definition and the OAM permission you have granted the user for the BO queue and the queue manager?"  This is something the mq admin would provide if that is not you.

Comment: Commands to run on the queue manager using example queue names and usernames: Main queue: `DIS QL(MAIN.QUEUE) ALL`, BO QUEUE: `DIS QL(BO.QUEUE) ALL`, permissions for BO queue: `dmpmqaut -m QueueManageName -t q -n BO.QUEUE -p username -e`, permissions on queue manager: `dmpmqaut -m QueueManageName -t qmgr -p username -e`